# Player traces waypoints differently depending on speed

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

The problem i guess is in the waypoints script somewhere.

If i make the player to walk slow let's say speed 1 or 2 he walk to the first waypoint then turn to the next waypoint when he get to the second waypoint instead going back to the original position he make some round walking and then walk back to the first waypoint. What i want it to do is not to walk to the first waypoint but to walk to it's original start position.

Another thing if i change the player speed to 7 i see it walking fast when he get to the second waypoint he turn left and keep walking left none stop. Like depending on the speed of the player he act different.

This is a video clip showing the player on speed 2:
The second player who walk faster is on speed 2 see what happen when he get to the second waypoint:

[video clip speed 2](https://youtu.be/tNGCoZrFBNw)

And this is the second player on speed 7

[video clip speed 7](https://youtu.be/rThlMbRSJuQ)

And this is the waypoints script in c#

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform[] waypoint;
    public float patrolSpeed;
    public bool loop = true;
    public int dampingLook = 4;
    public float pauseDuration;
    private float curTime;
    private int currentWaypoint = 0;
    public CharacterController character;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {


    }

    void LateUpdate(){

        if(currentWaypoint < waypoint.Length){
            patrol();
        }else{    
            if(loop){
                currentWaypoint=0;
            } 
        }
    }

    void patrol(){

        Vector3 nextWayPoint = waypoint[currentWaypoint].position;

        // Keep waypoint at character's height
        nextWayPoint.y = transform.position.y; 

        // Get the direction we need to move to
        // reach the next waypoint
        Vector3 moveDirection = nextWayPoint - transform.position;


        if(moveDirection.magnitude < 1.5){
            Debug.Log("enemy is close to nextwaypoint");


            // This section of code is called only whenever the enemy
            // is very close to the new waypoint 
            // so it is called once after 4-5 seconds.

            if (curTime == 0)
                // Pause over the Waypoint 
                curTime = Time.time; 

            if ((Time.time - curTime) >= pauseDuration){
                Debug.Log("increasing waypoint");

                currentWaypoint++;
                curTime = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {     
            Debug.Log("reaching in rotation " + moveDirection.magnitude);
            // This code gets called every time update is called
            // while the enemy if moving from point 1 to point 2.
            // so it gets called 100's of times in a few seconds  

            // Now we need to do two things
            // 1) Start rotating in the desired direction
            // 2) Start moving in the desired direction 

            // 1) Let' calculate rotation need to look at waypoint
            // by simply comparing the desired waypoint & current transform
            var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(nextWayPoint - transform.position);

            // A slerp function allow us to slowly start rotating 
            // towards our next waypoint 
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, 
                Time.deltaTime * dampingLook);

            // 2) Now also let's start moving towards our waypoint
            character.Move(moveDirection.normalized * patrolSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }  
    }
}
```

Maybe this strange behaviour of the player is ok since the physics ? So if it's too fast it's making this behaviour ? But it's strange. I think no matter the speed it suppose to walk between the waypoints no ?

Answer (score 1):

> If i make the player to walk slow let's say speed 1 or 2 he walk to the first waypoint then turn to the next waypoint when he get to the second waypoint instead going back to the original position he make some round walking and then walk back to the first waypoint. What i want it to do is not to walk to the first waypoint but to walk to it's original start position.

This is because when the enemy reaches your last checkpoint you set the `currentWaypoint` to 0. So the next frame the enemy is going to look for that waypoint. and since your starting position isn't a waypoint, he will never walk to that spot again. What you could do is make another waypoint that is at the same place as your enemies startingposition. that way it will walk back to his original position.

> Another thing if i change the player speed to 7 i see it walking fast when he get to the second waypoint he turn left and keep walking left none stop. Like depending on the speed of the player he act different.

This is because the movement (position) and rotation is not in sync with your patrolSpeed. you're only increasing the walk speed and not the rotationspeed. so every time your enemy has walked some distance, it needs to start rotating all over again. Try rotating your enemy with:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * patrolSpeed);
```

if thats still to slow try increasing the speedmodifier of the rotation.

Comment: How can i set a waypoint of the character start position ? I added the script to each of the thirdpersoncontrollers so i will add to the another two waypoints to the hierarchy each one for each player start position. But in the first two waypoints i'm using spheres is there any way to set waypoint just as position without adding gameobject ? For example to tell the player as way point to go to 0,0,0

Comment: And in the line currentWaypoint= 0; should i remove the line or keep it this way ?

Comment: Ok i added tow new empty objects and set in each the start position of the characters. The problem is with the line i changed  transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * patrolSpeed); this make the characters to move straight not to any waypoints. The old line make them to go to the waypoints but in strange way like in the video clips in my question.

Answer (score 0):

As for the first problem, you never store the "original" position--you just have waypoints.  So when the entity gets to the last waypoint, it sets course for the first waypoint, `waypoint[0]` since that's what `LateUpdate()` sets `currentWaypoint` to.

As for the entity changing behavior based on speed, two things to check-- is it actually reaching inside the `if(moveDirection.magnitude < 1.5)` block? If not, it's moving too fast in one frame to detect.  But it looks like you're always moving in `moveDirection` which actually is not affected by the rotation you calculate, unless your `Move()` function works differently than I expect, and so it's likely that the entity keeps heading in one direction because of that.

Comment: How do i store the original position of the characters i have two characters and in both i added the script each character start position is a bit different the first player is on x = -0.066 ,y = 0 ,z = 0 the second on x = -1.539 ,y = 0 ,z = 0 then how do i make it in the script storing the positions and set two new checkpoints as start points ?

Comment: Ah ok i will make tow new waypoints in the hierarchy then i will drag each waypoint to the specific character in the inspector as start position in the script i will change the line currentWaypoint= 0; to currentWaypoint= 2; is that right ? Just how do i set the start positions in the waypoints in the hierarchy ?

Comment: If the entities will always need to go back to that (specific) position, then sure add it to the array of Transforms.  But you'll definitely still want the line to reset currentWaypoint to 0 (otherwise it would just keep getting reset to 2 as soon as it was 3).  So, just make the entity transform the first member of the array rather than the last.

Comment: Ok i added tow new empty objects and set in each the start position of the characters. The problem is with the line i changed in WHQ answer: transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * patrolSpeed); this make the characters to move straight not to any waypoints. The old line make them to go to the waypoints but in strange way like in the video clips in my question.

Comment: I thought that line didn't look right but I didn't have time to think through the Quaternions (I'm still slow with them).

Comment: Will Molter but the way i did with the empty objects as waypoints of the start positions of each character is a good way to do it ? And i still wonder how to make it in the script instead creating empty objects and change the x value by my self. In the script i can find the character start position by doing in the Start function something like: character.transform.position but how do i add it to index 0 in the waypoint array ?

Comment: The thing is that Transform is a mutable object, so if you assign the actual player's Transform to the array, that waypoint will move.  So you can 1. copy the player's Transform during Start(), and assign that to waypoints[0], or continue using an empty object like you are now.  As far as not setting the x value yourself, make the empty object a parent (not a child!!) of the moving entity, and when you want to move the starting position, move that empty object.

Comment: Will you mean that the empty object i created in the Hierarchy as starting point instead to drag this empty object to to the ThirdPersonController i'm moving ? Or to leave it in the Hierarchy as paernt on it's own and move it on the scene as i want as a start position ? But how do i connect the empty gamepbject with the ThirdPersonController ? If i drag the empty gamepbject in the scene to change it's position it will not change the player(ThirdPersonController) position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118557/discussion-between-will-molter-and-thelost-lostit).